# to measure Contact Angle between 2 edges in an image

Tags: opencv, python-2.7

i need to find out contact angle between 2 edges in an image using open cv and python so can anybody suggest me how to find it? if not code please let me know algorithm for the same.

Answer (score 0):

- Simplify edge A and B into a line equation (using only the few last pixels)
- Get the line equations of the two lines (form y = mx + b)
- Get the angle orientations of the two lines θ=atan|1/m|
- Subtract the two angles from each other

Make sure to do the special case of infinite slope, and also do some simple math to get Final_Angle = (0;pi)